# The JScrollPane of the JTextArea is not working; Won't Scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am a novice programmer in Java Swing. I am trying to make a `JScrollPane` with the `JTextarea` so that the text will scroll. But the scroll is not working. Please help me with this. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am providing my code snippet here.

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("Hello.\n \n \n \n \n There.", 5, 10);
ta.setBounds(250, 60, 120, 60);

JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane(ta,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jp.setBounds(250, 60, 140, 80);
jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));

//jp.setViewportView(ta);
ta.setLineWrap(true);
panel.add(ta);
panel.add(jp);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) ..

Comment: .. 3) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead [use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: `..panel.add(ta);
panel.add(jp);` should be `..panel.add(jp);`. `ta` will appear because it has been added to `jp`.

Comment: This: `ta.setBounds(250, 60, 120, 60);` is going to mess you up bad. Never restrict the size of a component held by the a JScrollPane like this, since if you do this, it can't expand and the scrollbars will thus not work. Also it your use of null layout flags your code as newbie code, since it does not scale well at all. Learn the use of and then start using the layout managers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable tips. I would remember those and implement while writing the codes. I appreciate your time and suggestions

Answer (score 2):

By removing the below line:

```
panel.add(ta);
```

This will solve your problem since you are already adding the `JTextArea` to the `JScrollPane`
(Also the other comments are worth looking at :) )